# every real in (0,1) written as linear combination of the terms of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$  a infinite sequence of positive real numbers  such that every real number in $(0,1)$ can be written as a linear combination with  weights $n_1, n_2,...n_n \in \mathbb{N}$ of the $a_i$ ($a_1n_1+a_2n_2+a_3n_3+ ...$). How can I prove that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}a_i = 0$? And the viceversa is true?

Comment: It isn't true.  Take any sequence $\{b_n\}$ that works and define a new sequence $\{a_n\}$ by $a_{2n}=b_n$ and $a_{2n+1}=1$.  Then $\{a_n\}$ still has the property you want (since it contains the sequence $\{b_n\}$) but $a_n$ clearly does not approach $0$.

Comment: In my opinion the wording "linear combination" is misleading. It indicates that you only consider finite sums. But it seems that you allow any convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k n_k$.

Comment: lulu's comment shows that the best you can expect is that there is a subsequence $(a_{i_k})$ such that $a_{i_k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you regard $0$ as an element of $\mathbb{N}$, then it is wrong ( see lulu's comment).

However, we can show that the following are equivalent:

(1) $(a_i)$ has a subsequence $(a_{i_k})$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{i_k} = 0$.

(2) Each $x \in (0,1)$ can be represented as a convergent series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i n_i$.

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) : Let $x \in (0,1)$. It suffices to consider the sequence $b_k = a_{i_k}$ (which converges to $0$) and construct $n_k$ such that $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k n_k$. This is done inductively.

$k = 1$ : If $x \le b_1$, let $n_1 = 0$. If $b_1 < x$, let $n_1$ be the biggest number such that $b_1 n_1 < x$. In both cases $0 < x - b_1 n_1 \le b_1$.

Assume we have constructed $n_1,\dots,n_k$ such that $0 < x - \sum_{r=1}^k b_r n_r \le b_k$.

$k \mapsto  k+1$ : If $x - \sum_{r=1}^k b_r n_r \le b_{k+1}$, let $n_{k+1}= 0$. If $b_{k+1} <  x - \sum_{r=1}^k b_r n_r$, let $n_{k+1}$ be the biggest number such that $b_{k+1} n_{k+1} < x - \sum_{r=1}^k b_r n_r$. In both cases $0 < x - \sum_{r=1}^{k+1} b_r n_r \le b_{k+1}$.

This shows that $x - \sum_{r=1}^k b_r n_r \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. In other words,  $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k n_k$.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) : There must exist $x \in (0,1)$ such that in $x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i n_i$ we have infinitely many $n_i \ne 0$ (since the set of all $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i n_i$ in which only finitely many $n_i \ne  0$ is countable). Let $n_{i_k}$ be the subsequence of nonzero weights. In a convergent series we have $a_i n_i \to 0$, hence $a_{i_k} n_{i_k} \to 0$ which implies $a_{i_k} \to 0$.

Remark:

If you do not allow zero weights, then you do not have a chance to represent any $x \in (0,1)$ as a convergent series. In fact, the minimal value would be $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$.

Answer (score 0):

But if you assume that the weights are natural numbers it becomes true and follows from necessity condition of convergence of numbers series.
By naturals I mean $1,2...$

Comment: yes I forgot to add it. Anyway, the weights can be also 0